# Fitting a (logistic) generalized additive model with pygam in Python

Tags: regression, logistic, classification, generalized-additive-model, splines

I am trying to fit a (logistic) Generalized Additive Model with the pygam package.

I am given $d$ features $\mathbf{X} \in \mathbb{R}^{3}$ and want to fit a Generalized Additive Model.

Question 1: What is the best way to determine $\lambda_{i}, \ i=1,2,3$ ?

Question 2: How do I choose the Degrees of Freedom ?

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

from pygam import *

#Simulate data

df   = pd.DataFrame(np.random.uniform(0,1,size=(len(df), 3)),columns=['X1','X2','X3'])

Z = np.sin(df['X1']) + df['X2']**2 + np.cos(df['X3']) + np.random.normal(0, 0.1, len(df))

p = 1/(1+np.exp(-Z))

Y = pd.DataFrame(np.random.binomial(size=len(df), n=1, p= p),columns=['X1'])

#Fitting a GAM for the build-in lambda=0.6 

terms = [s(x, lam=0.6) for x in range(len(df))]
gam = LinearGAM(terms[0] + terms[1] + terms[2])
gam.fit(X, Y)

for i, term in enumerate(gam.terms):
    if term.isintercept:
        continue

    XX = gam.generate_X_grid(term=i)
    pdep, confi = gam.partial_dependence(term=i, X=XX, width=0.95)

    plt.figure()
    plt.plot(XX[:, term.feature], pdep)
    plt.plot(XX[:, term.feature], confi, c='r', ls='--')
    plt.title(repr(term))
    plt.show()
```

The above is an example for a fixed $\lambda$. I face an actually data set and seek appropriate values of each smoothness penalization $\lambda_{i}, i =1, \dots d$ for each feature  $X_{i} \in \mathbf{X}$ and the degrees of freedom (DoF). What is the correct way to do that ?

I did the following:

First, I looked at the partial dependence plots and then adjusted each lambda to improve the smoothness.

Second, I tried to implement the function **approx_lam()**, but it does not want to read a pandas data set, neither any modification to an array via df.to_numpy(). Here is the code with the corresponding error message

```py
from ISLP.pygam import approx_lam, degrees_of_freedom

DoF = [degrees_of_freedom(df.to_numpy(),terms[i]) for i in range(3)]

lam_vals = [approx_lam(df.to_numpy(),terms[i],df=5) for i in range(3)]

AttributeError: 'SplineTerm' object has no attribute 'edge_knots_'
```

What does this error mean ?